# How to place horizontal scrollbar at the top of an element?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a horizontal scrollbar. Is it possible to change the scrollbar position from the bottom of the element to the top, using only CSS?

Comment: There is no css method to style the default scrollers of browsers.
You would have to add a custom scrollbar, place it at the top of your element - then add proper javascript handlers to have the scroll effect - like animating left/right position, or using css transitions. The second method would be nicer and easier(in my opinion) to work with.

Comment: How I can do it cross-browser and easy?

Comment: There is a way. I'm just trying to get it right in a simple way.

Comment: @FrederikMoller if you'll make it work pls post it - i'm curious. Still - it has to be a cross browser compatibile solution, not a working draft...


user3775292 Please edit your question with the one from your comment - how to make a custom , cross-browser scrollbar (for example)

Comment: @wick3d - Please note that he does not want to change the scrollbar, he want it to be at the top, and not at the bottom of the content.

Comment: Frederik Moller, Yes, I don't want to change the scrollbar. It is the big problem for me too.

Comment: @user3775292 - Check the Answer I've put.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I've come up with this. Modify it to your needs, but this is all you need, you only need CSS, no JS. THIS DOES NOT CHANGE THE SCROLLBAR, it flips it to be at the top, instead of the bottom. If you want to change the scrollbar, then you will need a plugin (JS plugin).

```css
.Container
{
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.Content { width: 300px; }

.Container, .Content
{
  transform:rotateX(180deg);
  -moz-transform:rotateX(180deg); /* Mozilla */
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -ms-transform:rotateX(180deg); /* IE 9+ */
  -o-transform:rotateX(180deg); /* Opera */
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Content">
    Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is clever! Will there be no downsides if you put some dynamic content into it ?

Comment: Thanks, but I should support IE 8. Therefore I can't use this solution. But I think that it is the best solution in the future.

Comment: @wick3d - No, i just tested, I added a button on a click event in jQuery, and that button was upright. even a Ajax call for a page onto the content is upright. The only thing is... we all know it.. IE... wait, IE 8 and down, is our problem. you need a degree in rocket science to make it work LOL.

Comment: @user3775292 - Yes, that is a problem then. It still is possible, but I, myself, do not support IE 8 and down, so I dont even try. I know a lot of people says that this is bad if you dont support everything... but if someone wants to visit my website, eg, they need to have IE 9, or up. When are we ever going to reach a conclusion when everyone still supports all the old stuff? Im my eyes, I want to use the latest technologies only. But this is my opinion. I am glad to say, though, that it will work for IE 9 and up.

Comment: This causes the vertical scrolling direction to reverse

Comment: @PitaJ yeah, is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: This is not a proper solution. The nested content doesn't rotates, which displays them upside-down.

Comment: @Mohal did you try it? It works just fine. The rotation is applied to parent and child elements, so the child element is rotated twice.